# Function to identify which rows in a dataframe exceed "Mean" for the column

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a large database of crime statistics ("crimeData.csv") where the Columns are  the Category of crime and the Rows are the Addresses where the crime has occurred.  Thus, the data is the # of instances of the crime at given address.

I have put this into a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
relativePath=os.getcwd()
dataFilePath=relativePath+"/Resources/crimeData.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(dataFilePath)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to calculate the MEAN number of occurrences for each category of crime  (the columns in my df).  I did that here:

```
df.mean(axis=0)
```

Now comes the part where I am stuck.  I now need to write a function that does 2 things:

1. determine whether the number of crimes for each category at a given address exceeds the mean, and
2. prints the addresses where condition 1 is met for each category

EDIT:

I used Ted's suggestion below to try to highlight the cells that are above the mean:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
relativePath=os.getcwd()
dataFilePath=relativePath+"/Resources/crimeData.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(dataFilePath)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.mean(axis=0)
df.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.mean(), 'background-color: green', ''), axis=1)
df
```

This didn't appear to result in any change to the dataframe.  Still nothing being highlighted.  What am I missing????

EDIT #2:

This is the header of the dataframe:

```
                     Address  ARSON   ASSAULT   BAD CHECKS   BRIBERY  \
0         OAK ST / LAGUNA ST      0         0            0         0   
1  VANNESS AV / GREENWICH ST      0         1            0         0   
2   1500 Block of LOMBARD ST      0         8            0         0   
3  100 Block of BRODERICK ST      0         2            1         0   
4        0 Block of TEDDY AV      0         9            0         0
```

Comment: can you show an example of your `df`?

Comment: @Psidom: What is the best way to do that?

Comment: copy and paste a small proportion of your data frame as input, and also it would be best if you also include your desired output. See [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post the output of `print(df.head())`

Answer (score 0):

Put the column address in the index.

```
df = df.set_index('Address')
```

You should be able to use pandas `where` method to make all values less than the mean null and then drop the rows with `dropna`

```
df.where(df > df.mean()).dropna()
```

Here is an example where I create a 10 column, 2 row dataframe of random numbers between 0 to 1. Only the rows that have both columns greater than the column mean will be kept.

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2))
df.where(df > df.mean()).dropna()

          0         1
0  0.417022  0.720324
4  0.396767  0.538817
5  0.419195  0.685220
8  0.417305  0.558690
```

And to additionally inspect the original DataFrame, we can highlight the cells that are greater than the mean. The rows where there are two green cells are the ones we want.

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.mean(), 'background-color: green', ''), axis=1)
```

[image]

You should also be able to do:

```
df[(df > df.mean()).all(1)]
```

Comment: Ted, can you give an example what that would look like in actual code?  I tried to just create a variable with that code, but i got an error:

Comment: Ted--Thank you!  I tried to add your Green Highlighting code to flag the cells that are above the mean (see the EDIT in my original question).  Nothing changed.  What am I missing???

Comment: You can't take a mean of a string column. Put that column in the index and then proceed.